How to add aria-label containing post title into a post excerpt read more link in Wordpress 6.6.2?
I need to add a dynamic aria-label attribute to post excerpt "Read More" links to make them accessible for screen readers. I want to keep the default "Read More" text but add an aria-label like: 'Read More about: <some-post-title>'.
I tried replacing the link in functions.php but it didn't work out. Does this have something to do with how Wordpress renders the block theme's blocks? Do I have to use create-block and extend the core functionality somehow?
I tried to add this (and other variations) into my functions.php
function add_aria_label_to_read_more_link($link, $post) {
    $post_title = get_the_title($post->ID);

    // Include aria-label with post title
    $link = str_replace('href=', 'aria-label="Read more about ' . esc_attr($post_title) . '" href=', $link);

    return $link;
}
add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'add_aria_label_to_read_more_link', 10, 2);

And when the previous didn't work I tried this:
function add_aria_label_to_excerpt_more_link($link) {
    $post_title = get_the_title();

    // Include aria-label with post title
    $link = str_replace('href=', 'aria-label="Read more about ' . esc_attr($post_title) . '" href=', $link);

    return $link;
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'add_aria_label_to_excerpt_more_link');

I expected these to overwrite what's in the excerpt's read more link.
